# Disable parent window when child popup window is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have an aspx page that pops up in a child window. Is there a way to make the parent window non-accessible until the popup child window is closed?

For the record, I'm using the following jQuery code for opening and closing popup. On parent page:

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnLogos').click(function () {
                window.open("Logos.aspx", "List", "scrollbars=no, resizable=no, width=500, height=350");
            });
        });
```

The code above triggers when a button called "btnLogos" is clicked from the parent aspx file, then in the child popup window I have the following jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        var val = $('input:radio[name=myRadio]:checked').val();
        $(window.opener.document).find('#txtLogos').val(val);
        window.close();
    });
});
```

As you can see from the code above, not only does it close the popup child window, it also passes a value to a textbox in the parent window with a click of a button. My only issue now is to make sure the parent window is not accessible until that button in the child window is clicked. I tried using various solutions from CSS to Javascript but was not successful. I'm also aware that this can be done using showModalDialog, but this site has to operate on any browser, not just IE. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a modal dialog (jQuery dialog) instead of popup. Using dialog boxes are simpler and easier to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: The issue is, I need to popup an aspx page that already exists. I guess my questions are, can you open an aspx page inside a jQuery modal dialog? If so, can you pass a value from child window to parent window? Also does it work on all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Play around with this code in the pop-up:

```
 $(window).on("blur", function(){ ... });
```

This will fire every time the user leaves the window. Inside the argument function you should be able to make the window regain its focus, maybe using `$(this).focus()` or `self.focus()`.

I haven't tested this myself. Good luck!