# How to disable the parent window when ever we open a popup window?

Tags: javascript, php

I have write this code. I want to disable parent window when child window is open

```
<script language="javascript">   
 function popwindow(page) { 
OpenWin = this.open(page,"CtrlWindow","top=80,left=100,screenX=100,screenY=80,width=600,height=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no, scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
OpenWin.focus();
return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery models are meant for this purpose . Just see [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal), And
also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071153/disable-parent-window-when-child-popup-window-is-open?rq=1) for doing the same with java script.
Hope this helps !!